# Swift property observer and nil

Tags: ios, swift

I have a property observer code that must modify an iboutlet property:

```
@IBOutlet weak var canYouGuessLbl: UILabel!

var isNewUser: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        if isNewUser {
            canYouGuessLbl!.layer.zPosition = 5
            canYouGuessLbl!.hidden = false
        } else {
            canYouGuessLbl!.hidden = true  // Error at this line
        }

    }
}
```

This crashes at runtime because canYouGuessLbl! seems to be nil:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I'm not sure about the reason and how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers guys. It inspired me for this solution:

I had to put the action to perform in a separate function:

```
    func ifNewUser() {
    if isNewUser! {
        canYouGuessLbl?.layer.zPosition = 5
        canYouGuessLbl?.hidden = false
    } else if !isNewUser! {
        canYouGuessLbl?.layer.zPosition = 5
        canYouGuessLbl?.hideAndDisable()
    }
}
```

The main problem was with initialization, so first I check this in viewDidLoad:

```
ifNewUser()
```

Because the bool value receives its value very early by a segue, It's appropriate to check it first in viewDidLoad after all the variables including the IBoutlets are initialized.

Then for when the user is not declared a new user anymore, I keep the observer, but with call to function:

```
    var isNewUser: Bool? {
    didSet {
        ifNewUser()
        }
    }
```

Does the job.

Answer (score 2):

If your problem occur in scenario number one of Antonio's answer then you can solve it by declaring your isNewUser variable as optional and assign value to it on viewDidLoad method after canYouGuessLbl is fully initialized

```
var isNewUser: Bool! {

    didSet(newValue) {

        if isNewUser != nil && isNewUser! {

            canYouGuessLbl!.layer.zPosition = 5
            canYouGuessLbl!.hidden = false

        } else if isNewUser != nil && !isNewUser! {

           canYouGuessLbl!.hidden = true

        }

    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    isNewUser = false
}
```

Comment: @zelib: property observers are not invoked during initialization, so there's no reason to make it an optional.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few reasons why `canYouGuessLbl` could be nil when assigning a new value to  `isNewUser`:

- `isNewUser` is assigned a new value before `canYouGuessLbl` has been initialized (prior to `viewDidLoad`, such as in an initializer)
- an outlet has not been defined for `canYouGuessLbl` (i.e. the label control in interface builder has not been connected to the property)
- the view controller in IB is not connected to the implementation class (custom class in identity inspector)

**Update** - 
In the first case, you can fix by explicitly checking for not nil:

```
var isNewUser: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        if canYouGuessLbl != nil {
            if isNewUser {
                canYouGuessLbl.layer.zPosition = 5
                canYouGuessLbl.hidden = false
            } else {
                canYouGuessLbl.hidden = true  // Error at this line
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note however that doing that the label won't be updated (because it doesn't exist yet). It just prevents the exception.

Additional note: `didSet` (and more generally property observers) is not invoked when the property is initialized.

Comment: It's definitely 1. So is there anyway to have isNewUser observe perform after the iboutlet is initialized ?

Comment: Or maybe just put: canYouGuessLbl?.hidden = true  and the if statement in a function, with the ? instead of the !, call it once on viewDidLoad for when initializing the view, and leave the observer do the work on other cases. that might do the trick. Not sure if it's the best way.